# Nginx site for PHP-FPM status page returns "File not found"

Tags: php, nginx, datadog

In `/etc/php/7.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` I have set `pm.status_path = /status`. And in Nginx I have the following site configuration `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/datadog`

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;

    location ~ ^/(status|ping)$ {
        access_log off;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

I have tested that the status page is correctly setup using

```
SCRIPT_NAME=/status \
SCRIPT_FILENAME=/status \
REQUEST_METHOD=GET \
cgi-fcgi -bind -connect /run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock
```

Which returns

```
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8

pool:                 www
process manager:      dynamic
start time:           13/Nov/2017:22:05:44 +0000
start since:          5030
accepted conn:        1789
listen queue:         0
max listen queue:     0
listen queue len:     0
idle processes:       2
active processes:     1
total processes:      3
max active processes: 4
max children reached: 0
slow requests:        0
```

However, if I try to access the Nginx site using `curl http://localhost/status` I get the following error.

```
2017/11/13 23:32:57 [error] 885#885: *35 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /status HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock:", host: "localhost"
```

Comment: What is the value of: `$fastcgi_script_name` ? It looks like this may not be set...

Comment: How can I test this?

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing `$document_root` but there is no root directive in your server block

Comment: I have tried setting `root /var/www;` but it does not change a thing. Is there any other value I should set it too?

Comment: Have you copied your fastcgi_params file to that location?